# ExtJS mapping XML grid

Tags: xml, extjs4, mapping

I tried to map an xml to an extjs grid but nothing happens... 
This is my code

```
Ext.require([
'Ext.data.*',
'Ext.grid.*'
]);

Ext.onReady(function(){
Ext.define('Book',{
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: [
        // set up the fields mapping into the xml doc
        // The first needs mapping, the others are very basic
        {name: 'type', mapping: 'type'},
    ]
});

// create the Data Store
var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    model: 'Book',
    autoLoad: true,
    proxy: {
        // load using HTTP
        type: 'ajax',
        url: 'forecast.xml',
        // the return will be XML, so lets set up a reader
        reader: {
            type: 'xml',
            // records will have an "Item" tag
            record: 'Item',
            idProperty: 'ASIN',
            totalRecords: '@total'
        }
    }
});

// create the grid
var grid = Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
    store: store,
    columns: [
        {text: "Type", flex: 1, dataIndex: 'type', sortable: true},
    ],
    renderTo:'example-grid',
    width: 1200,
    height: 200
});
});
```

I have the easiest xml possible but i dont understand how to map correctly !
This is my xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<activities>
<activity>
    <type>Project</type>
</activity>
</activities>
```

If you have an idea dont hesitate ! I tried writting : mapping: 'activity > type' but it didin't work too ...

Answer (score 0):

Found it guys!

Just had to change the reader:

```
reader: {
            type: 'xml',
            // records will have an "Item" tag
            root:'activities',
            record: 'activity'
        }
```

Because my record is activity !

If someone needs help dont hesitate!